# Xamarin Method 'Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.IGeolocator.GetPositionAsync' not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Esta me retornando um erro:

> "Method 'Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.IGeolocator.GetPositionAsync'
>   not found"

Na versão IOS esta funcionando bem, porém no Android alguém poderia me dar uma dica? 
É meu primeiro app em `Xamarin`

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace LocationSampleApp
{
    public partial class LocationSampleAppPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LocationSampleAppPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnTeste.Clicked += BtnGetLocation_Clicked;
        }

        public async void BtnGetLocation_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await RetreiveLocation();
        }

        private async Task RetreiveLocation()
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            if (locator.IsGeolocationAvailable && locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
            {
                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
                if (position == null)
                    return;

                txtLang.Text = "Latitude " + position.Latitude.ToString();
                txtLong.Text = "Longitude " + position.Longitude.ToString();
            }
            else{
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Home", "OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: voce incluiu a biblioteca no projeto android?

Comment: certifique-se de quanto trabalhar com alguma biblioteca, a mesma deve ser instalada em todos os projetos (Portable, iOS, Android e UWP).

Comment: sim esta instalada, no projeto LocationSampleApp.Droid -> "Packeges" Xam.Plugin.Geolocator tem que instalar e mais algum lugar ?

Comment: Faz o seguinte, deleta as pastas BINS e OBJ de todos os projetos depois faz um restore dos pacotes! o Xamarin é cheio desses detalhes, as vezes sempre preciso fazer isso quando passo por este tipo de problema!

Comment: funciono :D.. deleta as pastas BINS e OBJ de todos os projetos depois faz um restore dos pacotes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleta as pastas BIN e OBJ de todos os projetos e em seguida faz um RESTORE dos pacotes! O Xamarin tem muito desses pequenos detalhes! ;) Espero ter ajudado!